# How to make dispatches synchronous

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk, dispatch

I have an the following function that is executed on button click:-

```
const modelClick = async(modelcategory, modelname)=>{
        const curr_model = allModels.filter(model => model.model === modelname && model.version === version)
        console.log("curr_model= ", curr_model[0]);
        await dispatch(setModel(curr_model[0]))
        await dispatch(getModelsOfType(curr_model[0]['model category']))
        console.log("models=", models);
        let temp;
        temp = models.filter(model => model.modelname === curr_model[0]['model_type'])
        console.log("temp inside modelClick= ", temp);
}
```

dispatch(getModelsOfType(curr_model[0]['model category'])) : This function queries the dynamodb and update the global redux state 'models'. I then want to filter the models based on type.

THE ISSUE i am facing is that the code below the dispatch gets executed before the state gets updated. It gives an error saying models is undefined. I want to run it synchronously so that the filter line gets executed only after models is updated. How can that be achieved ?

Here is the action creater function:-

```
export const getModelsOfType=(modeltype)=> async(dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type: GET_MODELS_OF_TYPE_REQUEST
    })
        let params = {
            model_type: modeltype
        }
       axios
        .post(`${BACKEND_URL}get-models`, params, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        })
        .then((res)=>{
            console.log("DYNAMO DB RESULT= ", res.data.Items)
            dispatch({
                type: GET_MODELS_OF_TYPE_SUCCESS,
                payload: res.data.Items
            })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("err >>", err);
            dispatch({
                type: GET_MODELS_OF_TYPE_FAIL
            })
        });
}
```

Comment: In your `getModelsOfType` action you can do `await axios.post...` or `return axios.post...` but I think `models` will still be a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) so maybe use an effect or return the new models from your action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of dispatching the action in the component. what you can do is dispatch the second action inside the first actions then block.

```
export const setModel=(your arguments)=> async(dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
      type: ACTION_REQUEST
  })
     axios
      .post(// make API call)
      .then((res)=>{
          dispatch({
              type: ACTION_SUCCESS,
              payload: res
          })

          // now dispatch the second action here . 
          dispatch(getModelsOfType(your arguments))
      })
      .catch((err) => {
          console.log("err >>", err);
          dispatch({
              type: ACTION_FAILURE
          })
      });
}
```