# What is the proper way to make dependent api call in Reactjs Redux Redux-thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I want to show data in one component at the first load time. I have an API call and the second API is depending on the first API response. How can I manage this call sequence and error handling? If anyone has an example link it would we very good for me because I am new in `Reactjs` and `Redux`.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for these two API calls you are trying to make.

Comment: Please take a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67639505/how-to-make-dispatches-synchronous/67639708#67639708

Answer (score 0):

I have an example. I make 2 API calls. I need to register a user (first request) and his partner. In order to register the partner (second request), I need to take `the token` from `first request response` and pass it as a `header` at second request:

Register function:

```
 const register = () => {

    const data = {
      eMail: email,
      password: password,
    };

    const partnerData = {
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
    };

    axios
      .post("/register", data)
      .then((firstResponse) => {
       //do sth
 
          return axios
            .post("/registerPartner", partnerData, {
              headers: { Token: firstResponse.data.token },
            })
            .then((secondResponse) => {
              history.push("/home");
              window.location.reload();
              return secondResponse.data;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log("Error in second request");
            });
       
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error in first request");
      });
  };
```

Comment: Better to flatten that Promise-chain, or use `async/await`. Why nest logic when the code you are using was designed to fix "nesting hell"?

Comment: Please let me know how would you rewrite the code. I'm opened for optimizing it . :)

Comment: You can, in the first `.then` return the `axios.post` Promise, and just move the nested `.then` to the outer chain.

Comment: Thank you, I will write again my api calls.