# Wait for get request response before continuing with a post request in axios

Tags: reactjs, http, post, axios, get

I have tried to use async/await in the createSwap function but it did not work for me. Before creating a request, I want to run the getSlotDetails function to set the slotDets so that it can be used in the post request below. However, the createSwap function does not wait for the getSlotDetails function to complete before sending the post request. How do I fix this?

```
  const [slotDets, setSlotDets] = useState([]);
  const getSlotDetails = (moduleCode, slotId, slotType) => {
        axios
          .get(`https://api.nusmods.com/v2/2020-2021/modules/${moduleCode}.json`)
          .then((response) => response.data)
          .then((data) => data.semesterData[0])
          .then((semesterData) => semesterData.timetable)
          .then((timetable) =>
            timetable.filter(
              (slot) => slot.classNo === slotId && slot.lessonType == slotType
            )
          )
          .then((result) => {
            setSlotDets(result);
          });
      };
    
  const createSwap = (
    moduleCode,
    slotType,
    currentSlot,
    desiredSlots,
    completed,
    reserved
  ) => {
    dispatch(createRequest());
    getSlotDetails(moduleCode, currentSlot, slotType);
    axios
      .post(
        "http://localhost:3001/api/v1/swaps",
        {
          module_code: moduleCode,
          slot_type: slotType,
          current_slot: currentSlot,
          desired_slots: desiredSlots,
          completed: completed,
          reserved: reserved,
          venue: slotDets.venue,
          startTime: slotDets.startTime,
          endTime: slotDets.endTime,
          day: slotDets.day,
        },
        {
          headers,
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        dispatch(createSuccess());
        setTimeout(() => {
          dispatch(resetSwap());
        }, 2000);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response.data);
        dispatch(createFail(error.response.data));
        setTimeout(() => {
          dispatch(resetSwap());
        }, 2000);
      });
  };
```

Comment: Instead of having two different functions, maybe make two API calls inside the same function? Check out the comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67832623/what-is-the-proper-way-to-make-dependent-api-call-in-reactjs-redux-redux-thunk/67832942?noredirect=1#comment119934662_67832942 They might be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
const makeTwoRequests = async () => {
 try{
   const firstResponse = await axios.get(FIRST_URL);
   if(firstResponse.status === 200){
     const firstResponseData = firstResponse.data;
     const secondResponse = await axios.get(SECOND_URL);
      
     if(secondResponse.status === 200){
       const secondResponseData = secondResponse.data;
     }
   }
 }
 catch(error){
   console.log(error)
 }
}
maketwoRequests()
```

`firstResponseData` and `secondResponseData` can be state variables instead of `const` for better access throughout the Component